# Android (Eclipse) - Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried to launch a very simple project app on Eclipse (it runs OK on my mobile cellphone) but I get the console message "Waiting for HOME('android.process.acore') to be launched". I have tried multiple time and waited long periods of time (in excess of 30 minutes) with no launch. Over the past 3 days I have read and tried various things that I read on Stackoverflow but I'm still stuck. I reinstalled Java, Java JDK, Eclipse ADT and Android SDK with no progress. My project consists of 3 cases that basically transfer between each other to display a video file. The logcat message when I first get the "Waiting for HOME.." message is:

---

```
08-21 21:47:15.610: I/dalvikvm(53): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-21 21:47:15.620: I/dalvikvm(53): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-21 21:47:15.720: D/dalvikvm(53): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 2% free 851K/864K, paused 28ms+3ms, total 93ms
08-21 21:47:15.960: V/NatController(50): runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -F natctrl_FORWARD) res=0
08-21 21:47:16.130: V/NatController(50): runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -A natctrl_FORWARD -j DROP) res=0
08-21 21:47:16.310: V/NatController(50): runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -t nat -F natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING) res=0
08-21 21:47:16.340: E/logwrapper(276): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-21 21:47:16.360: V/NatController(50): runCmd(/system/bin/ip rule flush) res=255
08-21 21:47:16.380: E/logwrapper(277): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-21 21:47:16.400: V/NatController(50): runCmd(/system/bin/ip -6 rule flush) res=255
08-21 21:47:16.410: E/logwrapper(278): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-21 21:47:16.440: V/NatController(50): runCmd(/system/bin/ip rule add from all lookup default prio 32767) res=255
```

---

I am new to Android/Java/Eclipse and have been making progress in learning to program Android/Java apps. I would appreciate any help in resolving my problem because I am very frustrated in trying to solve without adequate experience.

My AVD settings are:

---

Name: AVDx
Device: Nexus S (4.0', 480 x 800, hdpi)
Target: Android 4.4W - API Level 20
CPU/ABI: Android Wear ARM ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Hardware keyboard present
Skin with dynamic hardware controls
Front and Rear Camera: None
Ram: 343,  VM Heap:32,  Internal Storage: 200MB,  SD Card: 128MB

Comment: Simply re-run the app (CTRL + F11)

Comment: @Terry Why u r not using real devive to run programs through adb.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ARM emulator. That is available "out of the box" but is slow. [Set up support for the x86 emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm) and use the x86 emulator images.